# GNOME control centre online accounts not verified with Google

Tags: gnome, google, online-accounts, gnome-control-center

In trying to sign in to my Google account on GNOME, I get the following error.

[image: Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app]

Steps:

1. `$ gnome-control-center online-accounts`
2. Click "Add online account"
3. Type in Google login.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

I think GNOME needs to verify. Have raised an issue with gnome-control-centre.

https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/13404638?hl=en

Comment: You need to enable usage of "untrusted" applications in Google security.

Comment: tried allowing "less secure apps" but hasn't fixed

Comment: @Pilot6  I tried that; still not working.

Comment: @Pilot6 Good idea, but didn't work for me either